# Custom Community Login Page - Stuck in loop

Tags: visualforce, community

I am customizing the CommunitiesLogin page using VF but am having troubles directing to this customized page.  When navigating to *my_community_url/login* I see the standard, out of the box login page.  When navigating to *my_community_url/CommunitiesLogin* my browser gets stuck in a loop.

I have my Community set up as Active Site Home Page = CC_Home, Inactive Site Home Page = CC_Home and the login page set as the Visualforce Page CommunitiesLogin.

Here is my CommunitiesLoginController:

```
global with sharing class CommunitiesLoginController {

global CommunitiesLoginController () {}

// Code we will invoke on page load.
global PageReference forwardToAuthPage() {
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    String displayType = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('display');
    return Network.forwardToAuthPage(startUrl, displayType);
}

//code to invoke custom login page
global PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    return new PageReference(Site.getPathPrefix() + '/SiteLogin?startURL=' +
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(startURL, 'UTF-8'));
}}
```

Here is my CommunitiesLandingController:

```
public with sharing class CommunitiesLandingController {

// Code we will invoke on page load.
public PageReference forwardToStartPage() {
    return Network.communitiesLanding();
}

//code to invoke custom login page
public PageReference forwardToCustomAuthPage() {
    String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
    return new PageReference(Site.getPathPrefix() + '/SiteLogin?startURL=' +
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(startURL, 'UTF-8'));
}

public PageReference forwardTocustomStartPage() {
    return new PageReference('/apex/CC_Home');
}

public CommunitiesLandingController() {}
}
```

Here is the first line from the CommunitiesLogin page:

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" controller="CommunitiesLoginController" 
action="{!forwardToCustomAuthPage}" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
```

Here is the first line from the CommunitiesLanding page:

```
<apex:page id="communitiesLandingPage" controller="CommunitiesLandingController" 
action="{!forwardTocustomStartPage}" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
```

Any guesses as to what is causing this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by removing the action call in the CommunitiesLogin page.

Updated code:

```
<apex:page id="loginPage" controller="CommunitiesLoginController" title="{!$Label.site.site_login}">
```